# Reading huge s3 file line-by-line in java using s3Object.getContent() not working propertly stopping without any exception

Tags: java, amazon-s3, java.util.scanner

I have a huge s3 file to parse in a java app.

using `s3Object.getContent()` method I'm not able to read whole file because it stops without any exception to catch.

this my example code

```
try (InputStream in = s3file.getObjectContent()) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      //do something
    }
}
```

- I'm able to read (parse) more than 100.000 rows and then stops reading the inputStream with no reason
- no exception got

these the constraint :

- I don't want to download the whole file
- I don't want to use setRange because I don't know bytes per rows

```
GetObjectRequest rangeObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key);
            rangeObjectRequest.setRange(0, 1000); // retrieve 1st 1000 bytes.
```

do you have a best practice method to solve my problem?
tried to find similar questions but no-one solved mine

Comment: You have to read the file *one line at a time.* You cannot read the whole thing into [virtual ...] memory at once.

Comment: what do you mean?